# Generating Polygons from Image (Filled Shapes)

Tags: java, c#, image-processing, graphics, polygons

I'm trying to generate polygons from a preprocessed world map,
What i have done so far is:

1: Generated a contour map for each of the countries, it looks like this:
[image: Countour of each of the world countries]

2. From here i filled each of these countries with an random color like this:
   [image: Filled World map]

So far ive tried to just select a random pixel in the countour image and followed the line around until i hit the start point. This did give me a relatively good result, without about 90% accuracy on the polygons, However some countries dissapeared totally.

[image: Drawing generated polygons]

So what i wish to do is to have a array of coordinates for each of the countries in this map in a sorted manner so it can be represented as a Polygon. Do anyone know how to achieve this?

I have not found any algorithms suited for my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered creating a svg image? You would specify the contour lines, indicate that they should form a closed curve and be filled with a color of  your choice.

Comment: I can sadly not use SVG in my application, But could the SVG give me desired result automaticly, or would i have to define these manually?

Comment: the color-fill would be produced automatically (just add a `fill` attribute to your contour polyline ).

Comment: Which countries did disappear? Were they swallowed by others or did they remain uncolored? Of course you will never match everything, e.g.: islands to their mainlands..

Comment: Primarily Russia dissapeared. We had some troubles following the countour lines because some countries have lines that would create a endless loop. We solved this by backtracing stepes and selecting a alternative route (Avoiding this loop). Im not sure why russia dissapeared, But im primarily looking for a algorithm which is known to solved the problem im facing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are vectorizing tools out there but if you want to code it (it is a hard task) do this:

1. **scan image for black points**

   store all points in some `list` of `(x,y)` coordinates
2. **add connection info to all points**

   this will need **huge amount of memory** if not coded properly so add grouping info to which points is each point connected (remember just indexes).
3. **add usage flag to point**
4. **find polylines between joints**

   **joint** is point with more then `2` connected points so

   1. find such point `i`
   2. go through its connected points until another join point `j` is hit without going twice through any point. That is why you need the usage flag. Store this path as `polyline`
5. **find closed loops**

   It is similar to **#4** but you need to step through `polylines` to go back to the start point. Remember `polylines` as `polygons`

So you will need structures similar to this:

```
struct pnt
 {
 int x,y; // coordinate fo point
 int used; // usage flag for later use
 List<int> ix; // list of indexes of all points connected to this point
 };

struct polylin
 {
 List<int> ix; // list of point indexes
 };

struct polygon
 {
 List<int> lin; // list of polyline indexes
 List<int> dir; // direction of polyline (forward/backward)
 };

List<pnt> pnts;
List<polylin> plins;
List<polygon> faces;
```

If your image points has holes inside then you will need to handle them by additional image processing or by connected points finding with some treshold distance.